# NavigationDrawer: Child Activity to Main Activity different fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have a standard NavigationDrawer Application where I can switch different fragment (Section A, Section B) with MainActivity.
Fragment Section A has list of Item. On selection of item DetailActivity will be started showing details of the item. In detail activity I have a button which onClick should show the MainActivity and switch to different fragment Section B.

Please help on achieving this.

Comment: Where is the problem? `OnClick` run MainActivity and switch to fragment `Section B`. You probably need to pass some data indicating that switching is needed. This can be achieved by intent's bundle extras.

Answer (score 0):

For switching to different fragment on your MainActivity, pass some data on intent's bundle indicating that fragment to be switched.

In MainActivity read the bundle using getIntent() method and read the data you passed from DetailsActivity and replace the fragment based on the value.

Example:

In DetailsActiivty onClick:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, ManiActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fragment","section_b");
startActivity(intent);
```

In MainActivity onCreate method:

```
if(getIntent!=null){

        String fragment=getIntent().getStringExtra("fragment");

        if (fragment.equals("section_b")){
                        SectionB sectionB=new SectionB();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, sectionB);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }else{
                        SectionA sectionA=new SectionA();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, sectionA);
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change fragment, from one fragment to another fragment, using this code.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
sectionBFragment fragment=new sectionBFragment();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.group_layout, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

You can parse date section1 fragment to sectionB fragment Like this.

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the response, actually I solved it using

startActivityForResult method on starting DetailActivity and then onClick of button on Detail activity I did

setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();

and in the Fragment Section A I overrride the method

onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

Then switch the fragment sending message to MainActivity.

Let me know if this is a standard way in android. I am pretty new to android.